# Trying to calculate the total score based on answer's value in react.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, reactjs

**question part**

```
class PersonalityQuiz extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.mc = [];
        this.mc.push([
            { value: 1, text: "raphael" },
            { value: 2, text: "donatello" },
            { value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
            { value: 4, text: "michaelangelo" }
        ]);
        this.mc.push([
            { value: 1, text: "fluttershy" },
            { value: 2, text: "pinkie pie" },
            { value: 3, text: "rainbow dash" },
            { value: 4, text: "rarity" }
        ]);
        this.state = {
            score: 0
        };
  }
```

part for review based on answer total score should increase by the value of the answer (from 1 to 4). not much code afterwards

```
    handleShowScore = e => {
        let a = document.querySelectorAll("select");
        let newScore = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      var newScore = newScore + a[i].value;
    }
    
        this.setState({
            score: newScore
        });
  };
```

Comment: What is count? You need to show more code please.

Comment: that is basically the whole code. updated slightly, to make more sense ? thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating another `newScore` variable in the loop because `var` and `let` both create a new variable. So the original never gets updated. Change `var newScore = newScore + a[i].value;` to `newScore = newScore + a[i].value;` or use shorthand increment `newScore += a[i].value;`

Comment: thank you very much sir! worked as a charm! just updated to newScore = newScore + parseInt(a[i].value) to get sum as a result. cheers